# java stream get Map from Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say we have:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>
```

and I would like to get

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>
```

I used flat map:

```
myMap.values().stream().flatMap(p -> p.values());
```

to get Stream but I don't know how to use collect. I tride also:

```
myMap.values().stream().flatMap(p -> p.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

but this doesn't work

EDIT:

I have given data:

```
List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
List<Integer> numbers3 = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
List<Integer> numbers4 = Arrays.asList(7, 8);

Map<String, List<Integer>> innerMap1 = new HashMap<>();
innerMap1.put("first", numbers1);
innerMap1.put("second", numbers2);

Map<String, List<Integer>> innerMap2 = new HashMap<>();
innerMap2.put("third", numbers3);
innerMap2.put("forth", numbers4);

Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
outerMap.put("mon", innerMap1);
outerMap.put("tue", innerMap2);
```

and from this code I would like to get a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`
with data:

```
key: "first",  values: 1,2 
key: "second", values: 3,4
key: "third",  values: 5,6 
key: "forth",  values: 7,8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `Stream` of all the entries of the map, flatten with each entry of the map contained in the incoming entry's value and finally collect that into a map.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> result =
        outerMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(result); // prints {third=[5, 6], forth=[7, 8], first=[1, 2], second=[3, 4]}
```

This will not guarantee any order in the resulting map.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about the keys of the outer map, you may simply work with the stream of the `values()`, and collect by merging all the maps together into a new map like this:

```
final HashMap<Object, List<Integer>> result =
    outerMap.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll);
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints:

```
{third=[5, 6], forth=[7, 8], first=[1, 2], second=[3, 4]}
```